# Is there a way to record and precisely replay UI events on Android?

Tags: android, ui-testing

I assume the replay happens on the same setup of device model, screen orientation and the app UI. Thus, the exact coordinates of events are expected to be the same during recording and replay. The device can be rooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the paper about RERAN tool](http://www.lorenzobgomez.com/publications/icse13gomez.pdf) one can record and replay very low-level UI events using the `getevent` and `sendevent` tools, both available in Android SDK.

The [RERAN tool](http://www.androidreran.com/) can do the job, but it requires root and it is unclear if it can work on Android newer than 2.3.4. RERAN doesn't use `sendevent` because it has small lag that makes it unable to faithfully replay the event stream. Because the tool uses its custom solution instead of `sendevent`, it requires for the phone to be rooted.

Comment: I tried for newer versions and crashes during the translation of events. Have you tried it with newer versions too? Have you found something similar that works?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a few more tools,
but not really a documentation that can explain
all the internals.

I guess people dealing with Android internals
and the Android OS should have more ideas with
how to go about it.

This one (replaykit) works very well, although they don't expose the main source code just the binary files and documentation
https://github.com/appetizerio/replaykit
(and supports controlling multiple devices)

The one mentioned in another answer herem called RERUN (http://www.androidreran.com/) and the following one
 (which is bash oriented):
https://github.com/Cartucho/android-touch-record-replay

Relay on pushing a compiled binary to your phone,
a command which allows to send the recorded events into the OS's
event stream.

Replay kit probably does it internally, or they have
another method.

If someone can give more info or tools, this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The RERAN tool is outdated and it needs root to record from a device and replay back **only** to this particular device with the particular Android version.

Check out appetizer-toolkit. It works with non-root devices with ADB debugging. And it can replay to devices with the same aspect ratio as the recording device.
https://github.com/appetizerio/appetizer-toolkit